# Handling an authentication page returned by an axios request in vue

Tags: vue.js, axios, payload

I have a vue app that sits behind a firewall, which controls authentication. When you first access the app you need to authenticate after which you can access the app and all is well until the authentication expires. From the point of view of my app I only know that the user needs to re-authenticate when I use axios to send off an API request and instead of the expected payload I receive a 403 error, which I catch with something like the following:

```js
import axios  from 'axios'
var api_url = '...'

export default new class APICall {
    constructor() {
        this.axios = axios.create({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            baseURL: api_url
        });
    }
    // send a get request to the API with the attached data
    GET(command) {
        return this.axios.get(command)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response && response.status === 200) {
                    return response.data; // all good
                } else {
                    return response;      // should never happen
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                if (err.message
                    && err.message=="Request failed with status code 403"
                    && err.response && err.response.data) {
                    // err.response.data now contains HTML for the authentication page
                    // and successful authentication on this page resends the
                    // original axios request, which is in err.response.config
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Inside the catch statement, `err.response.data` is the HTML for the authentication page and successfully authenticating on this page automatically re-fires the original request but I can't for the life of me see how to use this to return the payload I want to my app.

Although it is not ideal from a security standpoint, I can display the content of `err.response.data` using a `v-html` tag when I do this I cannot figure out how to catch the payload that comes back when the original request is fired by the authentication page, so the payload ends up being displayed in the browser. Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried wrapping everything inside promises but I think that the problem is that I have not put a promise around the re-fired request, as I don't have direct control of it.

Do I need to hack the form in `err.response.data` to control how the data is returned? I get the feeling I should be using an interceptor but am not entirely sure how they work...

**EDIT**

I have realised that the cleanest approach is to open the form in `error.response.data` in a new window, so that the user can re-authenticate, using something like:

```js
var login_window = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
login_window.document.write(error.response.data)
```

Upon successful re-authentication the `login_window` now contains the json for the original axios `get` request. So my problem now becomes how to detect when the authentication fires and `login_window` contains the json that I want. As noted in [Detect form submission on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347325/detect-form-submission-on-a-page), extracting the json from the formatting window is also problematic as when I look at `login_window.document.body.innerText` "by hand" I see a text string of the form

```
JSON
Raw Data
Headers
Save
Copy
Collapse All
Expand All

status  \"OK\"
message \"\"
user    \"andrew\"
```

but I would be happy if there was a robust way of determining when the user submits the login form on the page `login_window`, after which I can resend the request.

Comment: What I understood from all this, you want to re-authenticate a user when your `axios` request returns with 403. Why don't you just implement something like showing an overlay on your window asking user to authenticate (where you can also show the content returned from request). You can use https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue package for this purpose.

Comment: @junaidrasheed No, that's not the problem. I can ask the user to re-authenticate in an overlay window or otherwise. Instead the problem is to capture the data coming back then the original request is resent after the user has re-authenicated. I certainly *do not* want to (directly) display the content from the request to the user as this is json data that is used by the app.

Comment: I dont think put html code in response is a good idea. Why dont you create a new vue component in frontend, then you write all the html and logic of sending and capture response there, but it not always appear in the page. Then, when you receive the error, you $emit an event. And in the app.vue you set to always listen to that event, if the event is listened, the vue component will appear.

Comment: Not sure if I understand - when the user re-authenticates it gets a response with generic "ok authenticated" and you want to re-send original GET request *or* from the re-authenticate request you get back data that would be in the original GET if the user session would not expire?

Comment: @MichalBieda The only way that I can detect that the user needs to re-authenticate is when a axios request sent by my code receives a 403 error. When this happens as part of the error, specifically in `error.response.data`, I receive a string for an HTML form that the user can use to re-authenticate. If I display this form to the user, and they successfully re-authenticate, then the authenication process refires my original API request, sending back the data I want. My problem is that I don't see how to capture this data, since the request comes from the authentication form, not from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to override the `<form>`'s submit-event handler, and then use Axios to submit the form, which gives you access to the form's response data.

*Steps:*

1. Query the form's container for the `<form>` element:

   ```js
   // <div ref="container" v-html="formHtml">
   const form = this.$refs.container.querySelector('form')
   ```
2. Add a `submit`-event handler that calls [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the submission:

   ```js
   form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
     e.preventDefault()
   })
   ```
3. Use Axios to send the original request, adding your own response handler to get the resulting data:

   ```js
   form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
     e.preventDefault()

     axios({
       method: form.method,
       url: form.action,
       data: new FormData(form)
     })
     .then(response => {
       const { data } = response
       // data now contains the response of your original request before authentication
     })
   })
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/competent-stallman-t46gl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

Comment: Attaching the event listeners on the page is proving problematic (there are several login forms but for some reason `document.forms` is empty...) but modulo this annoyance, which I expect to solve, this works. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting. If the target form has an ID, I would query for that form. In any case, you might want to ask a new question about that to see if any solutions arise. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

I would take a different approach, which depends on your control over the API:

- **Option 1**: you can control (or wrap) the API

  1. have the API return 401 (Unauthorized - meaning needs to authenticate) rather than 403 (Forbidden - meaning does not have appropriate access)
  2. create an authentication REST API (e.g. POST https://apiserver/auth) which returns a new authentication token
  3. Use an Axios interceptor:

```js
this.axios.interceptors.response.use(function onResponse(response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // no need to do anything here
    return response;
  }, async function onResponseError(error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    if ("response" in error && "config" in error) { // this is an axios error
      if (error.response.status !== 401) { // can't handle
        return error;
      }
      this.token = await this.axios.post("auth", credentials);
      error.config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${this.token}`;
      return this.axios.request(config);
    }
    return error; // not an axios error, can't handler
  });
```

The result of this is that the user does not experience this at all and everything continues as usual.

- **Option 2**: you cannot control (or wrap) the API

  1. use an interceptor:

```js
this.axios.interceptors.response.use(function onResponse(response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // no need to do anything here
    return response;
  }, async function onResponseError(error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    if ("response" in error && "config" in error) { // this is an axios error
      if (error.response.status !== 403) { // can't handle
        return error;
      }
      if (!verifyLoginHtml(error.response.data)) { // this is not a known login page
        return error;
      }
      const res = await this.axios.post(loginUrl, loginFormData);
      return res.data; // this should be the response to the original request (as mentioned above)
    }
    return error; // not an axios error, can't handler
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I will see if I can get Option 2 to work (I don't have control over the API).

Comment: As far a I can see this doesn

Comment: As far as I can see this is not enough ad I don't have the data to the call `this.axios.post(loginUrl, loginFormData)`. I first need to wait for the user to complete the form on the `loginUrl` page, detect this and then fire the axios response.