# Detect form submission on a page

Tags: javascript, request, axios

I have a vue app that sits behind a firewall, which controls user authentication. The only way that I have of detecting when the user needs to re-authenticate is when the axios requests sent by my app receive a 403 error. When this happens the server also returns a web page, which I see as, `error.response.data`. This page asks the user to re-authenticate via an embedded form that, when completed, authenticates the user and sends back the output from my app's original request.

My questions is how can I get the user to re-authenticate and then capture the data from my request that is returned? I can send the user the authentication page, for example by using:

```
var login_window = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
login_window.document.write(error.response.data)
login_window.focus()
```

but then I don't see how to determine when the user has authenticated. When this happens, `login_window.document.body.innerText` contains the json data from my app's request, which my apps needs but which I don't want to show to the user. When doing this "by hand", I also have not succeeded in extracting the json from `login_window.document.body.innerText` as the json structure has been stripped and it now looks something like this:

```
JSON
Raw Data
Headers
Save
Copy
Collapse All
Expand All

status  \"OK\"
message \"\"
user    \"andrew\"
```

This question tries to reduce my previous question down to a javascript problem. There may be a better way to do what I want using `axios`; see [Handling an authentication page returned by an axios request in vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327960/handling-an-authentication-page-returned-by-an-axios-request-in-vue) for more details.

Comment: Are you asking for a vanilla JS solution in this question (as opposed to Axios in the other question)?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override the `<form>`'s submit-event handler, and then use [`XMLHttpRequest` to submit the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript), which gives you access to the form's response data and status code. A status code of `200` implies that the user is authenticated, and the response data should contain the response of the original request before authentication.

*Steps:*

1. Query the form's container for the `<form>` element:

   ```js
   const form = document.querySelector('#container > form').querySelector('form')
   ```
2. Add a `submit`-event handler that calls [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the submission:

   ```js
   form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
     e.preventDefault()
   })
   ```
3. Use XHR to send the original request, adding your own response handler to get the resulting data:

   ```js
   form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
     e.preventDefault()

     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
     xhr.addEventListener('load', e => {
       const { response } = e.target
       const data = JSON.parse(response)
       // data now contains the response of the original request before authentication
     })
     xhr.open(form.method, form.action)
     xhr.send(new FormData(form))
   })
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/exciting-monad-3d7vv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js&theme=dark)